# Subset data based on Shiny user input

Tags: r, shiny

Right now I am making a shiny application which displays histograms for weather predictions based on some data according to different hours. The user has to choose the hour from the slider and according to that histogram changes but right now I have to write the hour input all the time and I want to make it a function so that I don't have to write it all the time.

```
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("superhero"),

  # Application title

  titlePanel("DLR-VALUES(normal_error) FOR DIFFERENT STATIONS"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      #implementing radio buttons
      radioButtons("p", "Select station-id",
                   list("ALNMRGA1"='a', "COOKOLV1"='b', "COOKOLV3"='c',"DRSS1ST1"='c',"GSHTEM1"='d',"GSWSILM"='e',"GSCFTY1"='f',"GSD5531"='g',"GSHASET"='h',"GSHTEM2"='i',"GSNPRM1"='j',"GSOAKSK1"='k',"ROSSLEX1"='l',"OR_Ln60_1"='n',"COOKOLV2"='o')),      
      textInput("name", "HOURS", ""),
      #slider input for bins of histogram
      sliderInput("HOURS",
                  "RATING BY HOURS:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 48,
                  value = 1)),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
)

# Define the server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

     if(input$p=='a'&& input$HOURS==1){
       normalized_dlr_error<-print(ty_normal_new_whole_data$normal_error[ty_normal_new_whole_data$Prediction_by_hours=='1'])
     }
     if(input$p=='a'&& input$HOURS==2){
       normalized_dlr_error<-print(ty_normal_new_whole_data$normal_error[ty_normal_new_whole_data$Prediction_by_hours=='2'])
     }

     if(input$p=='a'&& input$HOURS==3){
       normalized_dlr_error<-print(ty_normal_new_whole_data$normal_error[ty_normal_new_whole_data$Prediction_by_hours=='3'])
     }
     if(input$p=='a'&& input$HOURS==4){
       normalized_dlr_error<-print(ty_normal_new_whole_data$normal_error[ty_normal_new_whole_data$Prediction_by_hours=='4'])
     }
     if(input$p=='a'&& input$HOURS==5){
       normalized_dlr_error<-print(ty_normal_new_whole_data$normal_error[ty_normal_new_whole_data$Prediction_by_hours=='5'])
     }
     if(input$p=='a'&& input$HOURS==6){
       normalized_dlr_error<-print(ty_normal_new_whole_data$normal_error[ty_normal_new_whole_data$Prediction_by_hours=='6'])
     }
     if(input$p=='a'&& input$HOURS==7){
       normalized_dlr_error<-print(ty_normal_new_whole_data$normal_error[ty_normal_new_whole_data$Prediction_by_hours=='7'])
     }
     if(input$p=='a'&& input$HOURS==8){
       normalized_dlr_error<-print(ty_normal_new_whole_data$normal_error[ty_normal_new_whole_data$Prediction_by_hours=='8'])
     }
     if(input$p=='a'&& input$HOURS==9){
       normalized_dlr_error<-print(ty_normal_new_whole_data$normal_error[ty_normal_new_whole_data$Prediction_by_hours=='9'])
     }

     if(input$p=='a'&& input$HOURS==10){
       normalized_dlr_error<-print(ty_normal_new_whole_data$normal_error[ty_normal_new_whole_data$Prediction_by_hours=='10'])
     }
     if(input$p=='a'&& input$HOURS==11){
       normalized_dlr_error<-print(ty_normal_new_whole_data$normal_error[ty_normal_new_whole_data$Prediction_by_hours=='11'])
     }
     if(input$p=='a'&& input$HOURS==12){
       normalized_dlr_error<-print(ty_normal_new_whole_data$normal_error[ty_normal_new_whole_data$Prediction_by_hours=='12'])
     }
     if(input$p=='a'&& input$HOURS==13){
       normalized_dlr_error<-print(ty_normal_new_whole_data$normal_error[ty_normal_new_whole_data$Prediction_by_hours=='13'])
     }
     if(input$p=='a'&& input$HOURS==14){
       normalized_dlr_error<-print(ty_normal_new_whole_data$normal_error[ty_normal_new_whole_data$Prediction_by_hours=='14'])
     }
     if(input$p=='a'&& input$HOURS==15){
       normalized_dlr_error<-print(ty_normal_new_whole_data$normal_error[ty_normal_new_whole_data$Prediction_by_hours=='15'])
     }
 # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins

      hist(normalized_dlr_error, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just

```
 if(input$p=='a'){
   normalized_dlr_error <-print(ty_normal_new_whole_data$normal_error[ty_normal_new_whole_data$Prediction_by_hours==input$HOURS])
 }
```

That will use the value of the input to do the filtering.